# My motherboard has 2 ram slots . Why does CPU-Z and Speccy show that I have 4 slots?

Tags: motherboard

My motherboard has 2 ram slots . Why does CPU-Z and Speccy show that I have 4 slots ?

Gigabyte GA G41 MT S2P

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to CPU-Z's documentation, the information it gathers from the motherboard is the following:

- Vendor, model and revision.
- BIOS model and date.
- Chipset (northbridge and southbridge) and sensor.
- Graphic interface.

CPU-Z shows 4 RAM slots since your motherboard's northbridge (Intel G41 Express Chipset) can handle up to 4 RAM modules.

The fact that Gigabyte decided to install only 2 RAM slots on this specific motherboard is simply not taken into account.

Answer (score 15):

That's strange indeed, but the answers in [this forum thread](http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=683492) sound reasonable:

> The chipset can probably handle four sticks, but the board only
>   physically has two.

and

> A lot of the inexpensive manufacturers will omit parts on the PCB
>   itself to cut costs.

So, basically, CPU-Z and Speccy show to you what would be possible (using the information about/from the chipset), but the actual configuration the manufacturer chose can be different.

Comment: This isn't as uncommon as you think.  Market segmentation is like  Marketing -101.