# Laptop reporting wrong count of RAM slots?

Tags: memory

I have a Lenovo Z710 laptop and I noticed Task Manager and other programs show that the laptop has 4 memory slots. I opened the back of the laptop where things like disk and RAM slots are but there are only two memory slots each with 4 GB modules which gives the 8 GB of RAM the laptop has. Now the question is where are the other 2 slots? Are they not there and wrong amount of memory slots are reported or are they hidden somewhere? I've heard some manufacturers hide them under the keyboard. I would look but I'm worried it'll void the warranty.

Anybody has any experience with this?

Comment: You will have to check with the manufacturer.  Either they can tell you where they are, or they will tell you there are only two ( in which case, they just screwed up and did not change the default description in the bios to say there are only 2 slots that they pinned out on the board ).

Comment: I guess they screwed up as they say the RAM can be upgraded to 16 GB.

Comment: Related: [My motherboard has 2 ram slots . Why does CPU-Z and Speccy show that I have 4 slots?](http://superuser.com/questions/370212/my-motherboard-has-2-ram-slots-why-does-cpu-z-and-speccy-show-that-i-have-4-sl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computer has two memory slots according to the [official user guide](http://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/z710_ug_en.pdf) (see page 37 and 38)

> If two DDR3L SDRAMs are already installed in the memory slot, remove
> one of them to make room for the new one