# Why are the number of available RAM slots reported different with different tools? Who is right, the manufacturer or the tools?

Tags: memory, motherboard, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Y700-15ISK laptop that came with 16GB (2x8GB) RAM. On the seller's website it indicated that there were 2 of 4 RAM slots used, which sounded great to me - meaning that I can expand the RAM further.

I've used different tools to determine the actual number of RAM slots, such as Task Manager(Win 10), CPU-Z, Speccy and wmic, as suggested here [[How can I detect the amount of memory slots I have?](https://superuser.com/questions/331282/how-can-i-detect-the-amount-of-memory-slots-i-have]). The problem is that they report different things. See below:

(1). Task Manager:

[image]

(2). Speccy

[image]

(3). CPU-Z

[image]

(4). Wmic

[image]

The manufacturer's manual I found online indicates that there are only 2 x SODIMM slots. It also reports that the motherboard can take a max capacity of 16 GB (2x8GB, 2133Mhz), while other sources say that it can actually take upto 32GB (2x16GB) and has been tested. See [here](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-P-Y-and-Z-series/Lenovo-Y700-SSD-and-Memory-upgrade/td-p/2200745/page/12) and [here](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Lenovo/ideapad-y700) ... so i have reason to believe the manufacturer can make mistakes. Seems no one is certain. Who should I believe?

In the end, I've opened up the machine from the under side (following a guide like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oq7JFCarxzI)), and I seem to only find 2 slots (so far), but because of the differing results from the tool reports, I feel there are 2 more RAM slots. Could there be a possibility that there are another 2 RAM slots hidden on the other side of the motherboard (or in some place that i can't easily find), or is it simply that there are only 2 slots and the tools are reporting wrong results? Anyone with experience with disassembling this entire machine who might know the motherboard (Lenovo Allsparks 5A) inside out?

NB: I know this question is pretty similar to this one [ [Laptop reporting wrong count of RAM slots?](https://superuser.com/questions/1006375/laptop-reporting-wrong-count-of-ram-slots) ] ... but the machines are different.

Comment: "The manufacturer's manual I found online indicates that there are only 2 x SODIMM slots." - This is the only source you should trust.

Comment: "I know this question is pretty similar to this one" - You are right but the answer is the basically the same, according to your official documentation, your machine only has two DDR4 slots.