# Everything shows me that 3 of 4 Ram slots are used, but I see only 2

Tags: memory, motherboard

### Tools Used:-

> Bios, Cpu-Z, Speccy, Crucial scan, etc...

### Problem

They all say that I have **12GB**, 2 **Elpida** RAM chips, 1 **Samsung** and one free slot.  All I see is 1 **Samsung** and 1 **Elpida**, **without any free slots.**

It's an **Old** HP 8760w, I recently bought.Some versions of this laptop have 2, some 4, slots. What's happening?

[Crucial scan of my computer](http://bit.ly/2cvQUs1).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you asking if some versions of this laptop had 4 memory modules?  Your question isn't clear

Comment: Without exactly understanding the question, it sounds like you have on board soldered ram.

Comment: @djsmiley2k I didn't know ram could be soldered. That answers my question.

Comment: Related: [My motherboard has 2 ram slots . Why does CPU-Z and Speccy show that I have 4 slots?](https://superuser.com/q/370212/10259)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HP Elitebook 8760w/8770w has 4 physical memory slots, 2 are under the keyboard (Primary Memory Modules), and 2 are accessible from the bottom (Expansion Memory Modules). The system supports up to 32GB of RAM with a maximum 8GB per slot.

[Disassembly video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_RrJw7STac): Note at 6:09 the memory slots under the keyboard are clearly visible.

[HP EliteBook 8760w Mobile Workstation Maintenance and Service Guide](http://h20628.www2.hp.com/km-ext/kmcsdirect/emr_na-c02847569-1.pdf) 
See document pages 62-64 (PDF pages 70-72).

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you have a soldered in ram chip on the board, hense why you can't see the normal 'ram slot' that you expect.

There's plenty of questions about soldered ram sticks on [here](https://superuser.com/search?q=soldered%20ram)

Comment: This is incorrect in regard to this model, the 8760w/8770w has no soldered memory and it does have 4 slots, 2 are under the keyboard and 2 are accessible from the bottom of the unit.